# How to evaluate XSLT current-group elements to add a parent to a specific subset of elements?

Tags: xslt, xslt-grouping

I have a flat input of paragraphs with classes identifying the information type:

```html
    <body>
        <p class="Step">First step</p>
        <p class="ListBullet">List item</p>
        <p class="ListBullet">List item</p>
        <p class="ListBullet">List item</p>
        <p class="Information">Step information</p>
        <p class="CodeSample">Step sample</p>
        <p class="Step">Second step</p>
        <p class="Information">Step information</p>
        <p class="CodeSample">Step sample</p>      
</body>
```

I need to turn this into a format structured into steps, such as:

```html
<step>
    <ol>
        <li>List item 1</li>
        <li>List item 2</li>
        <li>List item 3</li>
    </ol>
    <info>Step information</info>
    <code>Step sample</code>
</step>
<step>
    <info>Step information</info>
    <code>Step sample</code>
</step>
```

I use a for-each-group function to form step groups and then iterate through the group elements, calling separate transformation templates for each child, as the number and type of child elements may differ for each step.

```xslt
    <xsl:for-each-group select="//p" group-starting-with="p[@class='Step']">
        <step>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
        </step>
    </xsl:for-each-group> 
    
    
    <xsl:template match="//p[@class='ListBullet']" >
        <li>    
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </li>                
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="//p[@class='Information']" >
        <info>    
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </info>                
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="//p[@class='CodeSample']" >
        <code>    
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </code>                
    </xsl:template>
```

However, I am unable to figure out how to add the  elements. I can make it appear either for all list items or none. I assume I'd need some kind of when/otherwise statement in the main template, but can't figure out how... Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you just want/need a nested group-adjacent:

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="//p" group-starting-with="p[@class='Step']">
    <step>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="tail(current-group())" group-adjacent="@class = 'ListBullet'">
          <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="current-grouping-key()">
              <ol>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
              </ol>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
              <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
          </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </step>
</xsl:for-each-group>
```

Comment: Thank you Martin! This works fine. Much appreciate your help.

Comment: How could I rework this if there are other classes to catch that need a different wrapper element? e.g. class = 'ListBullet' -> <ol> and class = 'UnorderedBullet' -> <ul> 
I can supply multiple group-adjacent criteria but how to rework the test statement in the xsl:when?

Comment: @Peter, I don't think we can solve such issues in the comment section of an answer to a question, I would probably do `group-adjacent="@class"` and then `xsl:choose/xsl:when test="current-grouping-key() = 'ListBullet'" with further tests for other classes like `UnorderedBullet` that need wrapping and with the `xsl:otherwise` as before. In any case, this is kind of covered territory for typical `group-adjacent` use cases so perhaps look at existing intros https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt-grouping/info and solutions, if you get stuck post a specific new question with all details.

Comment: Will do! Many thanks!